# Is there a way to compel TypeScript to return a certain type?

Tags: typescript

I have a general "fetcher" function as outlined below.  The problem I'm having is that TypeScript implies to it's calling code that the type can be any of the ones returned from any condition.

Is it possible, on the return, to tell TypeScript to only infer the returned type?

(initialNotes an initialTags are two different array types)

```
  async function fetcherFunc(entity) {
    await new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(resolve, 2000));
    if (entity === 'notes') {
      return initialNotes;
    } else if (entity === 'tags') {
      return initialTags;
    }
  }
```

Comment: Specify the return type as a union?

Comment: Specify `entity` as `entity: 'notes' | 'tags'` & remove the unneeded `if (entity === 'tags')` of the `else if`, this helps a bit, but doesn't get what you want exactly

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can either make it return a union type (`TypeOfNotesArray | TypeOfTagsArray`), or — if `entity` will be specified with a compiler-time constant — you could use a function overload:

```typescript
async function fetcherFunc(entity: "notes"): TypeOfNotesArray;
async function fetcherFunc(entity: "tags"): TypeOfTagsArray;
async function fetcherFunc(entity: "notes" | "tags"): TypeOfNotesArray | TypeOfTagsArray {
    await new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(resolve, 2000));
    if (entity === 'notes') {
        return initialNotes;
    } else if (entity === 'tags') {
        return initialTags;
    }
    throw new Error(`entity is expected to be "notes" or "tags", but was "${entity}"`);
}
```

If you call `fetcherFunc("notes")`, the result will be `TypeOfNotesArray`. If you call `fetcherFunc("tags")`, the result will be `TypeOfTagsArray`.